# how to know which host are trying to connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql

I need some utility which monitors which host are trying to connect my mysql server. Bascially i want all details of the users/host which are connected to mysql server OR even attempted to connect.

Thanks

Comment: You mean, a firewall?

Comment: you can enable your DB tracking for that

Comment: not an firewall. i want to kind of monitor tool / script anything which shows the users/host connected to mysql server or even attempted to connect with incorrect credentials

Comment: @AjayKadyan Can you give more details regarding "enable your DB tracking" . i had google but didnt find such

Answer (score 1):

Starting with MySQL 5.6, the performance_schema.host_cache table shows all the details you are looking for.

See
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/host-cache-table.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
show processlist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute following query with `root` user login to MySQL:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

This will give you details of all connections made to MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [JetProfiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/tour/). They have free version with [lots of features](http://www.jetprofiler.com/features/).

If you want to do via mysql command line then you can use answers provided by Omesh or Amrita.

Hope this help !